# Why is this linear regression false?

Tags: multiple-regression

**Context**
I'm working with real physical datas such as Temperature, Humidity, etc. My aim is to create a Linear Regression $F()$ about physical effect. It is known that :
[image: Heat Transfer]
*(image from youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVPNePuaEDk)*

$$\frac{dT_{water}}{dt} = a * {Q}_{cond} + b * {Q}_{conv} + c * {Q}_{ray} + d * {Q}_{evap}$$

Each ${Q}$ is mostly based on Temperature of water, Temperature of Air, Humidity, Temperature of recipient/floor, Temperature of sky, etc. (with $ln$, $log$, $x^4$,...)

For each ${Q}$, we have built some linear regressions $f_q()$. Then we know that $\frac{dT}{dt}$ is also a linear regression.

I tried two ways to find this Linear Regression $F()$ :

1. Using the initial formula and using each ${Q}$, trying to find $a,b,c,d$. I got a "strong multicollinearity" message and a $R^2 = 0.028$...
2. Using the physical data (Temperature of water, air, sky, etc.). I got a "strong multicollinearity" message and a $R^2 = 0.018$...

I had two feelings about these poor results :

- The fact that $\frac{dT_{water}}{dt}$ is dependent on previous temperature of the water. I mean on one side I will have $T_{water_{i}}$ and $T_{water_{i-1}}$ and the other side $T_{water_{i}}$.
- These real data is by its nature collinear...

Before jumping into the data to try to find out where is the problem, I tried dummy datas in two steps :

1. The first one is that `yi` is only function of `xi`
2. The second one is that one of the `xi` is also function of `yi-1` (because in fact y is a $\Delta T$ and one of the `xi` is the actual $T$ )

**Code**

I wrote some code to test this with dummy data. (It's quite long, sorry...):

```py
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, LinearRegression

#### Init values
init_value=25
measures = 10000
x0=[]
x1=[]
x2=[]
x3=[]
y =[]

#### Creating values
for i in range(measures) :
    if i == 0 :
        x2.append(init_value)
    else :
        #x2.append(x2[i-1]+y[i-1])        ##Second shoot
        x2.append(randint(28, 32))        ##First shoot
    x0.append(22)
    x1.append(randint(10, 32))
    x3.append(randint(50, 100))
    y.append(x0[i]/10 - 0.25*x1[i] - 0.15*x2[i] - x3[i]/1000 - 1)

#### Creating Dataframe
d = {'x0':x0,'x1':x1,'x2':x2,'x3':x3,'y':y,}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#### Normalization
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
normed_df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

#### Reg Lin
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(normed_df[['x0','x1','x2','x3']],normed_df['y'], test_size=0.3,)
lr=LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
train_score = lr.score(X_train, y_train)
test_score = lr.score(X_test, y_test)

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
print(f'Train score : {train_score}')
print(f'Test score  : {test_score}')
print(f'Coeff       : {lr.coef_}')
print(f'Intercept   : {lr.intercept_}')
```

**Note:** The reason why I'm using list to build it is that each column has different ranges and I also need to access the `i-1`. Moreover, I'm using a data frame because my original data are in this format.

**Problem**
*Edit* : These 2 problems has been resolved by @Kitter Catter (See in comment). I wasn't supposed to do normalization...

I'm facing two problem :

1. For the first shoot, why is the coefficient obtain wrong ?  Is there also a minimum of data to get it straight ? How can i guess what this minimum ?
   I have this result `[ 0.         -0.48770388 -0.8040215  -0.00443367]` and intercept `1.0346685997849714`...
2. In case of the second case (where one of the `xi` is also function of `yi-1`), would a linear regression work ? If not, what should be done (ideally getting the coefficient would be nice)?

In this dummy datas, I have built my coeff myself in 
`y.append(x0[i]/10 - 0.25*x1[i] - 0.15*x2[i] - x3[i]/1000 - 1)`. I should get a result close to `[ 0.1 -0.25 -0.15 -0.001]` with an intercept near `1`.

My output for the 1st case is :

```
Train score : 1.0
Test score  : 1.0
Coeff       : [ 0.         -0.89518229 -0.17089844 -0.00813802]
Intercept   : 1.0742187499999993
```

My output for the 2nd case is :

```
Train score : 1.0
Test score  : 1.0
Coeff       : [ 0.         -0.48770388 -0.8040215  -0.00443367]
Intercept   : 1.0346685997849714
```

**New Edit**

Then if it's working with dummy data, why it doesn't work with real data?

Comment: What exactly is "false"? Could you describe your problem in words and show us the results.

Comment: I've edit my question to add some results and explanations...

Comment: Have you looked at norm_df and what potential effect that had on your data?

Comment: Looking at unscaled gives coefficients:
Coeff       : [ 0.    -0.25  -0.15  -0.001]
Intercept   : 1.1999999999999744

Comment: @Tim given the clarification/that this question is somewhat answerable can we remove the hold? If you want this question may be misclassified as a programming/mathematical issue since the fit doesn't include any noise/inexactness.

Comment: @KitterCatter Indeed your right... Can someone explain me why ?
Moreover, it works for these dummy data... So why it doesn't work for real data when I know that they should stick to a linear regression due to physical properties ?

Comment: @Yassine Maybe you should take some time to think about what transformations on your predictors should do to your fit/the coefficients and intercept of your fit. By changing the scale or position you change the associated coefficients and intercept, but there should not be any net change. (eg $y=2x+1$ <=> $y = \frac{2}{a}(ax+b)+1-\frac{2b}{a}$ <=> $y=\frac{2}{a} x' +1-\frac{2b}{a}$)

Comment: At this moment the question contains mostly of code, please describe your question in words. See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated for some hints.

Comment: @Tim I tried to describe my problem as much as I can...

Comment: @Yassine Thanks, now it sounds more clear. We encourage users to asking questions that are easy to understand to potential answerers, since this adjusts your chance of getting it answered.